# This Query Gives me blank results too !!! Mysqli join tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image] 
This image shows there are some rows with NULL values i dont need them.

and also this query taking a long time to load..

Basically what i want is

am having some problem with getting the values from two tables of my database . i have two tables in my database 1 is mem and 2nd is payment mem stores name and drawid of users payment table stores draw and instalment of the user

User pays us every month . so if a user with a draw id 1 pays us in feb the values in two tables are mem drawid=1 and name = something payment draw = 1 and instalment=2

drawid in mem is same as draw in payment

so the tables has many to many relation. Now i need to find the list of all the members who have not paid even 1 instalment before 4th month.

```
 SELECT drawid,contact,dnd,mem.name,link,address, count(*) as numPayments,NULL numPaidPayments ,NULL PAID_CONTACT,NULL NAME_PAID FROM mem 
LEFT JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
drawid HAVING numPayments < '4'
UNION
SELECT NULL drawid,NULL contact, NULL dnd, NULL name,NULL link, NULL address,NULL numPayments,COUNT(*) as numPaidPayments ,contact PAID_CONTACT,mem.name NAME_PAID  FROM mem 
INNER JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
drawid HAVING numPaidPayments < '4' order by link desc
```

I AM tired of solveing this issue please suggest me something, i have been trying to solve this since a week ..

I am adding images for both the tables structure .

enter image description here
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard for us to help you without extra information. Tell us more about what you are trying to achieve with the query. Blank results means no results at all. Clearly a wrong query.

Comment: `$m` is your value or variable??

Comment: First of all, you can't select the fields that is not in group by, like link,address...

Comment: Explain about your table your join.

Comment: could you edit your code so the query will become readable (new lines between slected columns for example

Comment: There are two tables involved. Which column belongs to which table? And what are the tables' primary keys? Then: what is it you actually want to achieve. It's hard to guess from your query.

Comment: Strongly recommended https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: note: only 1 column mentioned in the group by part, where about 20 are in SELECT part: so where are the other 19?

Comment: i have added all the information i had to the question Hope you can understand now and help me a bit .

Comment: what if you copy this query into a tool like phpmyadmin (inserting an appropriate value for $m). Do you get errors?

Comment: Can I find the same `drawid` twice in table `mem`? (Your query makes it seem that no, because you group by drawid and access contact, address etc. if as there were only one record per drawid. But then you say this is a many to many relation, which would mean there are duplicate drawids in *both* tables.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner drawid in mem is unique but i payment tables it can be many ..

Comment: @lvo P There is no error, bur it gives me required results with also some blank results !

Comment: Okay that's a one to many relation. As you have technical IDs (`payment.pid` and `mem.mid`), you should either use them (i.e. replace payment.draw` by `payment.mid`) or get rid of them (i.e. make `mem.drawid` primary key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all you want is to count payments per mem:

```
select 
  m.*,
  (select count(*) from payment p where p.draw = m.drawid) as num_paid_payments
from mem m;
```

Limited to those with less than four payments:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    m.*,
    (select count(*) from payment p where p.draw = m.drawid) as num_paid_payments
  from mem m
) paid
where num_paid_payments < 4;
```

Or differently written:

```
select 
  m.*,
  coalesce(cnt, 0) as num_paid_payments
from mem m
left join
(
  select draw, count(*) as cnt
  from payment
  group by draw
) p on p.draw = m.drawid
where coalesce(cnt, 0) < 4;
```

Or differently written:

```
select 
  m.*, 
  count(p.draw) as num_paid_payments
from mem m
left join payment p on p.draw = m.drawid
group by m.drawid
having count(p.draw) < 4;
```

Comment: This is Awesome !!! But i need to fetch only the members where num_paid_payments is less than 4

Comment: Awesome You ARe Awesome .